# Mathematical notation for 'The tangent of $f(x)$ at the point $(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation, tangent-line

I've been looking around and can't seem to find correct mathematical notation for the tangent of a function at some point $(x,y)$.

For example, if a question asks to find the equation of the tangent of $f(x) = x^2$ at the point $(2,4)$, i'd solve it this way:

$$f'(x) = 2x$$
$$f'(2) = 4$$

So, let the tangent be denoted by the linear function $g(x)$

$$g(x) = 4x + c$$
$$g(2) = 4$$
$$g(x) = 4x - 4$$

Is there a mathematical symbol representing the tangent in this situation? Is what i've written the 'common practice'?

Comment: See [Derivative as a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Derivative_as_a_function):  The function whose value at a equals f′(a) whenever f′(a) is defined and elsewhere is undefined is also called the derivative of f.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard notation for the function $g(x)$ that you have defined there. However, thinking of the curve $C$ given by $y=x^2$ as a one-dimensional smooth manifold, you can denote the line represented by  $y=g(x)$ at an arbitrary point $x$ by $T_xC$. This is differential geometry notation for the tangent space of a manifold.

Comment: Just a suggestion to write the same thing when finding the equation of tangent is part of some bigger problem: Equation of tangent of $y=x^2$ at point $(2,4)$ is given by $y-4=\left({\frac{dy}{dx}}\right)_{\text{ at }x=2}(x-2)$

Comment: I would suggest saying that "the tangent to the function $f(x) = x^2$ at the point $(2,4)$ is the line $y = 4x - 4$." The question asks for "the equation of the tangent", not a function representing the tangent. The tangent itself is a line, and that line has equation $y = 4x - 4.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any symbol for the tangent line, but using the notation $g(x)=\dots$ looks fine to me, as long as you explicitly state that the function $g$ describes a tangent line. In general, the tangent to the graph of $f$ at the point $\left(a,f(a)\right)$ is given by
$$
g(x)=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a) \, .
$$
In this context, is simpler to use the [point-slope equation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/line-equation-point-slope.html) of a straight line.